# Selenium read text of hidden web element using Xpath

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm facing an issue in one of our automated script wherein I need to read the text of an element whose accessibility is hidden, since selenium can't read text of hidden elements. I checked other posts here as well and they suggest to execute javascript and read innerHTML using the element's ID. In our case the challenge is I can't use ID of the web element as its dynamic and changes each the time the page is loaded in web browser so I'm bound to rely on Xpath's, please find below the code of the element -

```
<div id="milestone_gwt-uid-2132" class="accessibilityhidden">Current Step: Referral Details</div>
```

Now id i.e. "milestone_gwt-uid-2132" is not static and changes whenever the page is loaded and I want to read the text - "Current Step: Referral Details". Is there any effective way to do that using Selenium Java?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share more of your HTML? Perhaps a couple of parent nodes?

Comment: in your id, is the word "milestone" remain same all time ...i mean in your id only the number 2132 is changed all time or the whole id is changed?

Comment: yes so basically prefix "milestone_gwt-uid-" is common for many elements and its the last number (2132) that changes

Comment: in that case, can u please share more of your html ...this div with some parent

Answer (score 3):

The method `getText` returns the visible text. Use `executeScript` to get the hidden text:

```java
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Current Step:')]"));
String hiddenText = (String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(
    "return arguments[0].textContent;", elem);
```

Note that assessing some hidden text in a test is probably a bad idea since it doesn't reflect what the user can see.

Comment: Have tried this already but this actually returns null in web elements as driver does not finds that element

Comment: It could be that the element is not yet created by the time the command is called. Try with a waiter and make sure that your element in not in a frame.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic `id` in your `XPath` in following way:

```
//div[contains(@id, "milestone_gwt-uid-")]
```

You can get `innerHTML` with following code

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath('//div[contains(@id, "milestone_gwt-uid-")]'));
String contents = (String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", element);
```

Comment: This is will in turn return lot of elements since in the application on which we are performing these tests, "milestone_gwt-uid-" prefix is there for many elements in DOM

Comment: Do those element also have `class="accessibilityhidden"` attribute?

Comment: No not always some elements are not hidden but some of those are

Comment: If you have few elements that differs only on their text node, you can only match them by parent or sibling element. Update (edit) your question with a little more `HTML`

Answer (score 0):

*Thanks! Works with MS Word Online!!
calling the method:*

```
String textFromEditor = getValue(driver.findElement(By.id(editorFieldId)));
```

*the body of method:*

```
protected String getValue(WebElement element) {
        try
        {
            String value = (String)((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].textContent;", element);
            return value;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return "can't get text";
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can assert the element by concatenating two Texts since the DOM will always contain a unique element.

Comment: Please improve your answer with a code example and references to documentation